# Курсор текста на JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, можно ли реализовать мигающий курсор ввода текста, допустим, в абзаце? Хочется сделать эффект печатающегося текста (собственно, уже сделал) и чтобы в конце курсор был.

Comment: можно, реализуйте, я разрешаю.

Comment: ой, большое спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: 1. gif с мигающим курсором в конце текста?
2. В текущей позиции показывать и делать невидимой вертикальную черту. Удалять ее нельзя, чтобы текст не съезжал.

Comment: Пожалуй, gif - это лучший выход, спасибо за совет.